# Saving options to chrome storage fails

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble with saving options to chrome storage. No errors in the console but just not saving the options. kudos to @wOxxOm for helping with the original bugs.

If you want the full code - most of it is below.

Any suggestions for fixing this?

Full snippet below.

```js
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var logolink = document.getElementById('logourl');
  var company = document.getElementById('companyname');
  var gst = document.getElementById('gstnumber');
  var footert = document.getElementById('footertext');
  chrome.storage.sync.set({
    logoStore: logolink,
 companyStore: company,
 gstStore: gst,
 footerStore: footert
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default value logoStore = 'original url' plus others.
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    logoStore: 'your url',
  companyStore: 'Your Company Name',
 gstStore: '123-123-123',
 footerStore: 'Footer'
  }, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('logourl').textContent = items.logoStore;
    document.getElementById('companyname').textContent = items.companyStore;
    document.getElementById('gstnumber').textContent = items.gstStore;
    document.getElementById('footertext').textContent = items.footerStore;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

HTML here.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Invoice Personaliser - Options</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="options.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class=container>
<div class="main">
  <h1>Invoice Personaliser - Options</h1>
   <form id="form">
<h3>Replacement Logo URL</h3>
   <input type="text" id="logourl">
<h3>Company Name</h3>
 <input type="text" id="companyname">
<h3>GST Number</h3>
 <input type="text" id="gstnumber">
<h3>Footer Text</h3>
 <input type="text" id="footertext">
    <button id="save">Save Options</button>
 </form>
   <div id="status"></div>

   </div>
   </div>
       <script src="options.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your options.js runs when there's nothing in the page yet. You also have it twice. Either move the tag down right before the closing `</body>` tag or put your addEventListener line inside restore_options function.

Comment: Thanks heaps! That fixed the first issue.  Unfortunately, the second wasn't resolved.

Comment: Error in response to storage.get: ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://hnekjedbdmcplaciaogghlheedpcdnpc/options.js:32:14)
    at HTMLDocument.restore_options (chrome-extension://hnekjedbdmcplaciaogghlheedpcdnpc/options.js:26:23)

Comment: Add `.textContent` after each document.getElementById('...')

Comment: Use devtools debugger: open the source code and set breakpoints inside save_options and restore_options, then reload the page (F5 key or location.reload() in console) and see what happens.

Comment: I just updated the post to include the latest code.  Any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried the debugger but can't really see anything helpful - it's quite possible I don't know where to look :(  I've updated the post and all code.

Comment: Could you update the question with expected / faulty behavior? All we have is "saving fails" - at what point, and how are you testing that it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Using .value after each getElementById('') - instead of .textContent it now works.